# Windows automatically sets start disk to Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have a kind of annoying problem with my Macbook Pro 15 2018. I have installed Windows 10 with Bootcamp, and it works very well. The only issue is that every time I boot into Windows the system somehow sets the default start disk to the Bootcamp partition, meaning I have to manually reset the start disk to Macintosh HD. Furthermore, I suspect that this affects the PRAM as I experience many kernel panics after the default start disk is changed. I can fix this by resetting the PRAM, but it gets tedious and annoying to do everytime i want to use Windows.

I'm running MacOS Mojave, and Windows 10. My system specs are:
Macbook Pro 15-inch, 2018
2,6 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4 ram
512 GB storage

Has anyone experienced similar problems, or have any idea what could fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: so, you mean when you boot from Windows and restart, it always boot using Windows but you want to have the option to chose from which OS you want boot? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, when i restart after booting to windows using the Option key, it always boots into windows, and i want the default to remain booting into OSX

Comment: Then, here is a solution for you: https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-assistant/start-mac-windows-macos-boot-camp-bcmp29b8ac66/mac

Comment: Yup, tried that. But everytime i boot into windows it reverts back to the bootcamp volume being the startup disk. Thats the issue im having

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208123, I assume you have tried this too then.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38572/how-do-i-set-os-x-to-boot-by-default , check this too.